# How to match partially a string in an array of Objects in Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm using the following:

- Node.js: 9.8.0
- Jest: 22.4.2

There's an array like the following being returned from myFunction:

```js
[
    ...
    {
        id: 00000000,
        path: "www.someUrl.com/some/path/to"
    }
    ...
]
```

And I want to match it against the following kind of array:

```js
const output = [
    ...
    {
        id: 00000000,
        path: "path/some/path/to"
    }
    ...
]
```

In a nutshell: **I want to totally match the id, but only partially the path.**

But I just don't know how... I've tried the following:

```js
expect(myFunction()).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(output));
```

But the gives me an error.

Answer (score 5):

I've solved with the following code:

```js
const output = JSON.parse(readFileSync('./myFunction.json', 'utf8'));

describe('Testing myFunction.', () => {
    test('Deafult test.', () => {
        const input = myFunction();

        input.map((value, index) => {
            const { imageURL, ...remaining } = output[index];

            expect(value).toMatchObject({
                ...remaining,
                imageURL: expect.stringContaining(imageURL)
            });
        });
    });
});
```